# Why create loops to get elements for events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The textbook I'm using to learn JavaScript uses the following code to display an alert dialogue whenever a user clicks on a paragraph:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0; i<paras.length; i++) {
 paras[i].onclick = function() {
  alert("You clicked on a paragraph.");
 }
}
```

I don't see the reason to loop through all the `p` elements, but instead identify them and simply attach the `onclick` event handler to it. Like this:

```
var paras = document.getElementByTagName('p');
paras.onclick = alert("You clicked on a paragraph.");
```

Doesn't that do the same thing? Why is it necessary to loop through the `p` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that absolutely does not do the same thing:

1. You simply cannot attach event handlers to an HTML node list (well, you *can*, but nothing will happen);
2. You're trying to set the "onclick" to the *result* of the `alert()` statement, not a function as in your example. (Doesn't really matter because it won't work anyway.)

Now there is a way to handle the clicks with just one event handler, but I'll let you keep reading your book :-)

*edit* — To elaborate on point 2, this:

```
alert("hi");
```

is a **function call**.  Its value will be whatever is returned from calling that function. Thus,

```
paras.onclick = alert("You clicked on a paragraph.");
```

sets the "onclick" property of the object that "paras" refers to, and it sets it to the value returned from `alert()` (which is probably always `undefined`).

As in the sample code from your book, things like "onclick" handlers need to be **functions**.  That's what's going on in the middle of your sample code: the "onclick" property of each individual `<p>` DOM element is being set to a function. *Inside* that function is the call to `alert()`.

Comment: I understand point 1, but not point 2. Could you elaborate on point 2?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have

```
​<p>​First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
```

So `var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");` will return a collection of `p` like

```
[<p>​First Paragraph​</p>​, <p>​Second Paragraph​</p>​, <p>​Third Paragraph​</p>​]
```

If you write `paras.onclick = alert("You clicked on a paragraph.");` then it won't work because `paras` is an array of some `p` elements not the `p` element itself and only an `html` element has an event, so you have to loop through the collection and add event handler for each `p` element individually.

Even if you have only one `p` then it will return an array with one `p` element inside it, i.e.

```
​<p>​First Paragraph</p>
```

And `var paras=document.getElementsByTagName("p");` will return`[<p>​First Paragraph​</p>​]`

So to add an event handler you can simply write

```
paras[0].onclick = function() { // 0 is the first element in the collection
     alert(this.innerHTML);
 }
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/AM97T/) is an example, I hope it'll help you to understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not work.

The function `document.getElementsByTagName` will return you an array of nodes because several nodes can have the same name (hence the plural for "Elements") : you can have several paragraph in you page, and this function will return them all. Even if you have only one paragraph, you will get an array containing one single element.

On the other hand, you could select the node with its ID by using the `document.getElementById` function. In this case, the result will be a single node, because IDs are supposed to be unique within a document.

```
var para = document.getElementByTagId('myParagraph');
paras.onclick = function(){ alert("You clicked on a paragraph.") };
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it now: the reason for the loop is because all the values are stored in an array and you have to go through each one individually and call the function.